# Find classes within <strong> element while scraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I want to retrieve the download links on a [soccer matches website](https://fullmatchsports.co/amiens-vs-psg-full-match-ligue-1-2018/?tab=download).

[image]

Using the following script I find the location of the surrounding element:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://fullmatchsports.co/amiens-vs-psg-full-match-ligue-1-2018/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
download = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-22276"]/div/div/p[3]/strong')
```

Next, I want to find the links within 'download'

```
links = download.findAll('a')
```

This results in the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

I don't understand why it doesn't find these classes. If I inspect the page, I see that the classes are part of 'strong'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either **Selenium** or **BeautifulSoup**:

- `findAll` is a **BeautifulSoup** method
- `download = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="post-22276"]/div/div/p[3]/strong')` is a **Selenium** `WebElement` and does not have a `findAll` method.

This is reason of the error. Here how you can get download links with Selenium:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get('https://fullmatchsports.co/amiens-vs-psg-full-match-ligue-1-2018/')
# wait until element will be clickable
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//p[contains(., "Download links")]//a')))

links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[contains(., "Download links")]//a')
```